# what is rc service (or rc.service)?

Tags: services

running `$sudo systemctl status rc` in my Ubuntu v18.04 I notices there is such a service:

```
● rc.service
   Loaded: masked (/dev/null; bad)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

can anyone tell me what it does?

Answer (score 6):

Debian’s systemd adds [a number of links](https://salsa.debian.org/systemd-team/systemd/blob/fef30053a9dd8babb4b1d874d392c508e394b6a4/debian/systemd.links#L57) to prevent obsolete initscripts from being run:

```
# Those services are useless under systemd. Mask them so they can't
# be run manually by accident.
/dev/null /lib/systemd/system/sendsigs.service
/dev/null /lib/systemd/system/halt.service
/dev/null /lib/systemd/system/reboot.service
/dev/null /lib/systemd/system/rc.service
/dev/null /lib/systemd/system/rcS.service
```

(In systemd, linking a unit to `/dev/null` tells systemd that it is “masked”.)

So `rc.service`’s sole purpose is to ensure that running

```
systemctl start rc
```

won’t run an `/etc/init.d/rc` script left over from some other init system (`file-rc`, `openrc` and `sysv-rc` all provide this file).